# boto3 client method using variable as the method name

Tags: python

I have a list of boto3 client methods that I want to iterate through, create a client, and do something with that.

e.g.

```py
methods = ['allocate_address', 'allocate_address', 'attach_volume']

client = boto3.client('ec2')

for method in methods:
    # below doesn't work
    bound_method = client.method # <-- I want to use the variable to set this
```

Can I do this?

Comment: Would using the getattr method in Python help? Example: `getattr(client, api_action)(**parameters)`. api_action will be the method. **parameters will be the parameter for each method.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56904466/boto3-client-method-using-variable-as-the-method-name#comment100354569_56904466) from [@krishna_mee2004](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4191049/krishna-mee2004), I was able to do this using:

```py
methods = ['allocate_address', 'allocate_address', 'attach_volume']

client = boto3.client('ec2')

for method in methods:
    bound_method = getattr(client, method)
```